# Is there any way to mount a DSBGA package IC on a breadboard?

Tags: integrated-circuit

Is there any way to mount a DSBGA package IC on a breadboard and test it? It does not have pins that normally fit in a breadboard. Instead, there are small spheres on the bottom of the IC which are the pins (see image below). What are the average costs for these method(s) (if any methods exist)?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Look for a "BGA to DIP adapter." These are small PCBs that have the footprint for the IC in question and route them to through hole pins which are on 2.54 mm grids suitable for breadboards.

[image: BGA to DIP adapter]

*Image from [Proto-Advantage](https://www.proto-advantage.com/store/product_info.php?products_id=3100180)*

Comment: Also consider a [BGA Socket Adapter](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=BGA+test+socket&t=opera&ia=web).  Tend to be pricey, but could come in handy.

Comment: Some places that sell the adapters will order the part for you and solder them onto the board for a surprisingly reasonable fee.

Comment: @JYelton How do all the pins connect though if half of them are on one side of the adapter board and do 'universal' adapters work for bga?

Comment: @Matthew3302 The adapter when plugged into the breadboard should straddle the center (like a DIP package). I'm not sure what you mean by 'universal' - be sure to match the pitch (distance between balls/pins). If the total number of pins isn't exactly the same, you can sometimes use an adapter meant for a larger pin count with a smaller pin count part by simply not using all of the pads/pins.